# postfix authenticate disable smtp port 25, but 587

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to make postfix not to auth users on port 25 but only on 587 and using STARTTLS.
I have tried may different confs, but no success so far.

main.cf:

```
    ...
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable =yes
    smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
    allow_mail_to_commands = alias
    allow_mail_to_files = alias

    smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
    smtpd_helo_required = yes

    smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated

    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
      reject_non_fqdn_sender,
      reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
      reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
      reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
      reject_invalid_hostname,
      permit_sasl_authenticated,
      reject_unauth_destination

    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    #smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    #smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

    smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv3, !SSLv2
    smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/smtpd.pem
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/smtpd.pem
    smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/postfix/smtpd.pem
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
    smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
    smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
    tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
    ...
```

master:

```
    # service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
    #               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
    # ==========================================================================
    smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    #  -o smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    #  -o content_filter=spamassassin
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    #  user=spamd argv=/usr/local/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
    #  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
    #  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    #  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
    #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    #smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    #  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
    #  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    #  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
    #  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
    #  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
    #  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
    #  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    #  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    #628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
    pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    ...
```

Maybe, I miss something..
Thank you

Comment: I can understand wanting to mandate TLS - which is a good idea - but why do you care what port users do this on?

Comment: Can you explain about the exact problem? The term no success was vague. Can you post the relevant maillog entry and any error message?

Comment: I have noticed that using thunderbird at the outgoing server settings, if I choose port 25 and security none, it accepts it without any problem. It works. All I want to do is to prevent that. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your `master.cf`:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  ...
```

And remove `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` from your `main.cf` leaving the default `no`.

Comment: I have made those changes but still, I can send emails via port 25 and sec. none.

Comment: Did you reload the postfix daemon? As this works for me, could you please post the current main.cf and master.cf after the change?

Comment: Won't port `465` still work with this config? Do we need to add something like `-o smtpd_tls_security_level=none` to `smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd`?

Comment: @TCB13 totally depends on what your main.cf looks like

Comment: @sebix my config is similar to the one at the OP.

Comment: Similar is not equal. Please start a new question, as your differs from this one.

Answer (score -1):

Please make the below change on master.conf .
Comment the below line .
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

Add the below line 
587      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

netstat -tulpan | grep -i master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587         0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 7168/master

Comment: How is this any better than the already-accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

In /etc/postfix/main.cf you will add/change

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

This will ENFORCE the use of TLS, so that the Postfix SMTP server announces STARTTLS and accepts no mail without TLS encryption

Then, in your /etc/postfix/master.cf you will override it for port 587 (the submission port) by overriding the parameter:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

This requires TLS for all submission (port 587) connections.